# Sending e.target as a DOM node in jest/enzyme

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

```
//test.js
const map = {};
  document.addEventListener = jest.fn((event, cb) => {
    map[event] = cb;
  });
const wrapper = mount(<AccordianDropdown />);

it('Should not close dropdown on document click inside', () => {
    map.click({
      target: <div role="button"/>,
    });
  });
```

This is my index.js file:-

```
   // index.js
    componentDidMount() {
        document.addEventListener('click', this.closeOnDocumentClick);
      }

      componentWillUnmount() {
        document.removeEventListener('click', this.closeOnDocumentClick);
      }

    closeOnDocumentClick = (e) => {
        // If event happened in the dropdown, ignore it
        if (!(this.ref && isFunction(this.ref.contains) && this.ref.contains(e.target)) && this.state.open) {
          this.setState({ open: false });
        }
      };
```

On running test getting this error `TypeError: Failed to execute 'contains' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.`. Please help me understand how to test this piece of code.

Comment: Any help on this, please?, Did you find a workaround for this ? I'm too getting this error

Answer (score 2):

Ok Found a solution for this,

In the wrapper object call the `getDOMNode()` method to get the DOM node(s) element(s).
If you pass this element as the event.target value. You will not get an exception.

If not you could create an element using JSDOM

```
const dom = new JSDOM();
const newDiv = dom.window.document.createElement("div");
```

and then

```
    test('...', () => {
        const mockedEvent = { target: wrapper.getDOMNode()[0] };
        wrapper
            .find('ClickAwayListener')
            .props()
            .onClickAway(mockedEvent);
    });
```

or If you just want to avoid the exception, `TypeError: Failed to execute 'contains' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.` pass null as the target to the simulated event or event callback handler.

```
    test('...', () => {
        const mockedEvent = { target: null };
        wrapper
            .find('ClickAwayListener')
            .props()
            .onClickAway(mockedEvent);
    });
```

Hope this code will help you.